# Adding Id Number In htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Can someone help me out please

Right i'm using smarty template engine and i have private messaging system but the problem is that i get this `The discussion ID is not defined` because

On list message page foreach message i've got this link

```
<a href="{$baseurl}/read-pm?id={php} echo $dn1['id']; {/php}</a>
```

So the url looks like this

`http://localhost/read-pm?id=6`

So how can i add the id number in htaccess

Example of my htaccess

english routes

```
RewriteRule ^/?read-pm        index.php?menu=read-pm&lang=en [L]
RewriteRule ^/?list-pm        index.php?menu=list-pm&lang=en [L]
RewriteRule ^/?new-pm         index.php?menu=new-pm&lang=en [L]
```

general routes

```
RewriteRule ^/?list-pm        index.php?menu=list-pm [L]
RewriteRule ^/?read-pm        index.php?menu=read-pm [L]
RewriteRule ^/?new-pm         index.php?menu=new-pm  [L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `QSA` flag to all of your rules:

```
RewriteRule ^/?read-pm        index.php?menu=read-pm&lang=en [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/?list-pm        index.php?menu=list-pm&lang=en [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/?new-pm         index.php?menu=new-pm&lang=en [L,QSA]
```

- `QSA` (Query String Append) flag preserves existing query parameters while adding a new one.